# Entity Framework table name convention

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using EF 6, have two simple POCO class as below:

```
public class Person
 {
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
 }

public class Company
{
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and my context

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context() : base("name=codefirst")
    {

    }
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Company> Corporation { get; set; }
}
```

And EF generated tables :
**dbo.Companies** and
**dbo.People**

My question is why one table name is People and other table name is Companies (I know why is pluralized).
I mean, One table use the property name, and the other table use the class name ?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Both use the type name, only they're pluralized. The plural of `Person` is `People`

Answer (score 8):

Both are mapped by using their **class name.**
The one that probably confused you is the mapping of the Person class. It is one of the EF pluralization rules, since people is the plural form of  person(meaning more than one person), EF mapped it as People.
On the other hand, it simply mapped the Company class as Companies.

You can turn off EF pluralization convention by adding this code in the `OnModelCreating()` method if you don't like it:

`modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();`

Comment: OP knows that EF does pluralization while creating tables and he doesn't want to stop it from happening.

Comment: @RBT Yes, but he was expecting Person class to be mapped as Persons. I explained that it won't be.

Answer (score 2):

Entity Framework (EF) model builder always refers to your class names while creating tables in database in code first approach. In your case it is `Person` and `Company`. EF never refers to properties in your context class while creating database tables.

While creating the table, it tries to pluralize the names so `Person` got pluralized to `People` and `Company` got pluralized to `Companies`.

Just as a quick test if you change the name of your `Company` class to `Corporation` then the table name will get created as `Corporations`. I've also changed the corresponding property name `Corporation` in context class to `FooBar`

Here is what I did to test it:

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
public class Corporation
{
    public int CorporationId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context() : base("name=codefirst")
    {

    }
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Corporation> FooBar { get; set; }
}
```

EF now goes ahead and creates `Corporations` table instead (plural of `Corporation`) and ignores the `FooBar` property name altogether which is present in the context class .

In your code it was a mere coincidence that you had named the property in your context class as `People` which happen to be plural of `Person`. This confused you and got you thinking.